# CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder not found

Tags: asp.net, cultureinfo

I want to add custom culture, I have added the following code but I am getting the following error:

> "the type or namespace CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder could not be found ,are you missing directive or assembly reference"

Although I am using `System.Globalization` and added `sysglobal.dll`.

```
string culture = "en-JO";
string name = "Jordan English";

CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
RegionInfo regionInfo = new RegionInfo(cultureInfo.Name);

CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder = 
      new CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder(culture, CultureAndRegionModifiers.None);

cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.LoadDataFromCultureInfo(cultureInfo);
cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.LoadDataFromRegionInfo(regionInfo);

cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.CultureEnglishName = name;
cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.CultureNativeName = name;

cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.Register();
```

Comment: Check your reference and the `using` statement again.

Comment: try to clean and rebuild the code-base.

Comment: (just a hint - I don't think it will solve your problem) CultureInfo and RegionInfo are defined in mscorlib.dll You probably don't need sysglobal.dll.